# Java - Linked List Storage Difficulty

Tags: java, indexing, linked-list, queue

I have a program containing a Linked List data structure to store custom TCP packet.

Test program reads in a packet, adds it to the Linked List queue, and immediately  prints the packet value (a timestamp value) for confirmation. This process is repeated 10 times in a while loop, so there are 10 packets in the Linked List queue.

Problem comes with a check on the queue values after all packets have been read in. The problem being that only the value of the last packet read in, is shown, despite the knowledge that there are 9 other packets with different values (supposedly) in the queue.

If someone could help me understand this seemingly black magic I would be most grateful.

```
public void readPackets() throws IOException {
    int counter = 1;

    while(counter < 10){
        packet = con.fillWIMPacket(packet);
        packetQueue.add(packet); 
        System.out.println("Packet " + counter + " added to Queue");
        System.out.println("Packet " + counter + " " + packet.toString());
        counter++;
    } 
}



public void printPacketValues(){

    System.out.println("Packet Queue size is " + packetQueue.size());


    for(int i = 0; i < packetQueue.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("Packet " + i + ": " + packetQueue.get(i));
    }

}
```

I should clarify that the println() methods of the first readPackets() is showing data in the correct order. However, the println() of printPacketValues() simply shows the value of the last packet 10 times..

Comment: Can you post any trace and/or the calling methods? Is any `IOException` being thrown?

Comment: Add the implementation for `fillWIMPacket` to your code. Looks like you might be returning the same instance that is passed as argument, in which case your queue contains 10 identical objects in it.

Comment: Why are you not using a for loop instead of the while ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(counter < 10){
    packet = new PacketType(); //change here and try once.
    packet = con.fillWIMPacket(packet);
    packetQueue.add(packet); 
    System.out.println("Packet " + counter + " added to Queue");
    System.out.println("Packet " + counter + " " + packet.toString());
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Why is it that a new instance should be create for the old to be earased. Shouldnt the old reference be overwritten?

Comment: @Jnanathan NO.Your linkedlist will contain a list of references to the same instance and modifying that one instance affects every entry in that linkedlist if you dont create new instance.